# Mixing vertical and horizontal splits in vim, from command line

Tags: merge, diff, split, vim

Title really says it all.  There is the -O option for opening splits vertically, and -o for horizontally, but trying to mix them doesn't seem to work.

My goal is to use g/vimdiff for 3-way file merging in mercurial in a way more like kdiff3 does.  This method would have the 3 files to be merged split into 3 vertical tabs across the top (my local version, the other version of the file I am merging it with, and the base version between the two), while the "output", or results of the merge, is a large horizontal tab stretched across the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a little kludgy, but it works:

```
vim -c "wincmd J" -O base diff1 diff2
```

(That's a verbatim control-W there)

Maybe there's a more elegant method, but this simply loads all of them as vertical and then moves the active (first) one to the bottom.

Comment: The "more elegant" way would be to use `wincmd J` instead.

Comment: Well, yours is more what I was thinking of as elegant, though you're right about that. (Of course I'm not sure how much difference there is internally between `wincmd {arg}` and `normal ^W{arg}`)

Comment: I love a good kludge, and this does the job. Specifically add a little bit of this in the .hgrc: filemerge.args = -c "wincmd J" -g -d -O $output $local $other $base

Comment: In case anyone else stumbled on this while trying to make TortoiseSVN use Vim as the merge tool, and display it the same way `git mergetool` does, the arguments in @user17925's solution translate to: `-c "wincmd J" -g -d -O %merged %base %mine %theirs`.

Answer (score 1):

Although Vim allows you to supply more than 2 files to be diffed, it doesn't particularly work very well for doing more than a 2-way diff.

At any rate, you're correct that you can't specify different ways to split using both `-O` and `-o`.  The best you'll get is either sourcing a script to run (via `-S 3way.vim`) or using `--cmd` arguments to setup the splits and change which buffers are displayed in those splits.

A potential 3way.vim, assuming you invoke vim as `vim -S 3way.vim localfile otherversion baseversion merged` would be

```
botright vsplit +b2  " Opens a split and focuses otherversion
botright vsplit +b3  " Opens a split and focuses baseversion
botright split +b4   " Opens a split and focuses merged
wincmd =             " Resize all windows so they share space equally
```